# Why random noise is eliminable by infinite repetition of testing?

Tags: psychometrics

In the field of psychometry, Classical Test Theory "CTT" presumes that in a test the observed test score is the result of the true score + error score. The last is thought to raise due to noise, i.e. factors other than the measured entity that affects measurement of that entity. Now, according to CTT if we repeat a test an infinite number of times, then the limit to the average observed test score would be the true test score. It is thought that infinite repetition would cancel out the noise effects thereby reaching at the true score.

> See: Cronbach, L. J., & Shavelson, R. J. (2004). My Current Thoughts
> on Coefficient Alpha and Successor Procedures. Educational and
> Psychological Measurement, 64(3), 391-418.
> https://doi.org/10.1177/0013164404266386
>
> In particular page 400.

Note: the error must not be a structured one. In other words it is thought that the noise factors are random. Also, the noise is independent across the repetitions.

EDIT: I came to know that the idea underlying this assumption is that the noisy factors may have opposing effects on the observed score, i.e. some of them may increase while others may decrease it, that when a test is repeated infinitely [on the same subjects] the average score of those randomly occurring independent noise factors would be zero, thereby making the observed score equaling the true score.

One suggestion is that this is because of the law of large numbers, which simply states that

> the average of the results obtained from a large number of independent
> identical trials should be close to the expected value and tends to
> become closer to the expected value as more trials are performed

Most of the examples I've seen about "expectation" is build probability derivations about random events. But here when a measurement is concerned which is what testing is doing, there is no reason to think that the expected value is the true score? Or in other words why should the expected value of the noise score be zero? Why should that be? even if we assume there is opposing noise effects that are randomly derived.

What is the basis for that assumption? Is it because the number of noise factors is finite? Is there a mathematical argument for that assumption that depends on Ramsey's theory or the alike? I mean we can have a Ramsey like situation if we think the test is repeatable but the noise factors are not because their total number must be finite, then of course we'll end up with an infinite tail of noiseless measurements. But, this is trivial.

It appears to me that the situation is about the average of randomly occurring possibly opposing actions that have random finite magnitudes and random directions. So, the idea is that the expected average of those at infinity is zero. I'm asking about the mathematical basis for that assumption. I mean why should they ultimately cancel each other, why they cannot keep persisting? Why there should be an expected value in such a situation in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think some care is needed in handling this issue. I agree that standard errors converge to zero (for common estimators, anyway), leading to confidence intervals whose widths converge to zero, but the phrased claim seems to imply that *prediction* intervals converge to a width of zero, which they do not.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for starting your participation with such excellent questions.  This comment is not specific enough to your situation of having increasing test items, but in general averaging more measurements improves results if the items are not biased and if the correlation between items being averaged is not close to 1.0.  It’s ironic that you don’t want too much consistency across items, otherwise the items are redundant and averaging them brings in no new information.

Comment: "why should the expected value of the noise score be zero"? If the expected value of measurement errors would be different than 0, there is a systematic component in the measurement errors, and systematic components by definition become part of the true score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation is correct. There is no mathematical reason why errors should be symmetric (let alone normally distributed), and neither is there a mathematical reason why measurements should be unbiased, i.e., the expected value is the true value. This is an assumption and all theory relies on it.

Note that if we assume $X=t+R,\ E(R)=0$, where $X$ is an observation (or rather a random variable interpreted as observation), $t$ is the "true" value, and $R$ is the error term, $E(R)=0$ is an *identifying* assumption, it makes sure that $E(X)=t$. If we allowed $E(R)=a$ with arbitrary $a$, $t$ would not be well defined, as changing $a$ and $t$ by some constant in opposite directions would lead to the same distribution of the observable $X$. In other words, there is no way to identify $t$ from even arbitrarily large amounts of data unless we assume $E(R)=0$ (or anything equally strong). The data will hold some information about the distributional shape of $R$, but nothing on where it's centered.

That is, it is more correct to say that $t$ is defined to be the expected value of the observations (to be approximated better and better if the number of independent observations grows), which may or may not be the "true value" you have in mind. Or rather, if you say "$t$ is the true value", your concept of a true value should be so that it coincides with the expected value of your observations.

If there is systematic measurement error, this may obviously be violated. But this cannot be addressed by the mathematics or the data. It needs to be addressed by (a) making sure that the measurement instrument works well, and (b) having a reasonable and well behaving concept of the "true value" of interest. This is hard and not always possible, and there is much literature on issues with this, for example in the social sciences, but also elsewhere (this includes by the way the controversial idea of "operational measurement theory", i.e., that any "true value" measured by a measurement procedure is implicitly constructed by the measurement procedure rather than objectively existing before being measured).

Comment: to OP, ie bias in your measurements is not a statistical problem and can only be identified/fixed by alternative measurement procedures, eg changing physical measuiring instrument

Comment: Very nice! So the matter is definitional. But, definitions needs to be justified. How you categorise the justification for defining a random error as one that is expected to converge on to zero by repeated testing. Is it apriori, if so, then is there a description of the sort of that apriori justification or argument. If it is aposteriori, then what empirical evidence is there for it. From your account I feel it is a pragmatic fix, although it appears to hold some apriori flavor.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar One could maybe make a subjective probability argument - given that the measurement procedure is as good as one was able to devise, one would expect it to be centered around the true value as there is no more reason a priori to expect values too high than too low. But ultimately it's just a thought construct, an idealised abstract setting. It can be justified as such, but this doesn't imply that there is an argument that any specific reality of interest behaves like that.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, If I understand you correct. You are saying it is not aposteriori. Your account looks like an apriori judgment though not a firm one. The justification for such idealized thought constructs that are not  apriori rules of thought, I think, is hard to categorize, this reminds me of philosophy of mathematics. So, I think your position is prudent! Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I'm not that familiar with your use of apriori and aposteriori, but it looks like I'd agree with this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you are asking but the fact that the expected value of the error variable in classical test theory (CTT) is zero is a property that follows by definition of the true score and error variables in CTT. It is a property that cannot be wrong (i.e., cannot be falsified in an empirical application) if you accept the definitions of the variables. You can find the details in the following paper (and especially in its Supplemental text A on CTT):

Steyer, R., Mayer, A., Geiser, C., & Cole, D. A. (2015). A theory of states and traits—Revised. Annual Review of Clinical Psychology, 11, 71-98.

https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-clinpsy-032813-153719

Supplemental text A:
https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/suppl/10.1146/annurev-clinpsy-032813-153719/suppl_file/cp11_steyer_suptexta.pdf